# What methods and variables are available to a view in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a very n00b question about Rails. What are the variables and methods available to a view in Rails? I had a problem today, from working on an existing project, where a method was missing from our `my_model_helper.rb` file. I didn't even know that methods in a `_helper.rb` were available.

I know, for example, that any instance variables from the controller are available from the view, but that's the limit of my knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already named what's available in views: instance variables defined in the controller and helpers. Helpers can be defined in `_helper.rb`-files and inside controllers as regular methods but you have to mark them with `helper_method` ([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method)).

Of course, methods defined in `_helper.rb` are available in any view but controller's helpers are available ONLY for views that are rendered with this controller.

I hope you already know about `params`, `request`, `response`, `session` and other core-methods to access/manipulate the state of user's request/response.

Comment: yes I knew about those other core methods, but sometimes it's hard to track down where things come from in Rails. Thanks!

Comment: Try this trick. Let's say you don't know the origin of `link_to` helper. In any view put: `<%= method(:link_to).source_location %>` and you'll know the path and line where it was defined.

Comment: Don't forget all the built-in ActionView Helpers: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers.html